# Category searches in Mapbox GL Geocoder

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js

How do you execute generic searches with the mapbox gl geocoder? By "generic" I mean searches for a type of place, not a specific place, e.g. "cafe". I want to be able to search for "cafe" or "grocery store" or whatever generic category and have the map put a marker on each place of that type found in the current viewport. It doesn't look like generic searches or any search that returns multiple results are supported. Is that correct? This would be a little surprising since OpenStreetMap seems to have the data necessary to support this kind of searching.
I've included types: 'poi' and a filter function that removes potential results if they do not have "cafe" or "coffee" in their obj.properties.category string. This reduces noise in the result suggestions, but when the user presses ENTER the result is still just of a single place (whichever one of the suggestions that was highlighted). There are no examples of this kind of general search in the documentation examples.

Note that this example already limits results to inside of New York city by using a bounding box. Also note that you would have to insert your own mapboxgl.accessToken to make this example work.

Here is a working basic react + mapbox gl setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import Geocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";
import './map.scss';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE';
const nyc_bbox = [-74.04848, 40.54217, -73.72479, 41.15114]

export class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      lng: -73.9392,
      lat: 40.8053,
      zoom: 14
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      zoomAnimation: false
    });

    const geocoder = new Geocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
      bbox: nyc_bbox,
      types: 'poi'
    })
    
    map.addControl(geocoder);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} className='mapContainer'/>
  }
}
```

And the accompanying scss file (./map.scss):

```
.mapContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

And also the ./index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map } from './map';

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <Map />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Application />,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. You can pass `poi` as the value for `types`, and define a `filter` function which inspects the `categories` property of each result to decide whether to keep it or not.

Comment: Where do you insert the filter function? Is it what you would put in the arrow function here? geocoder.on('result', (e) => {} )

Comment: See the documentation https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md

Comment: Defining a filter function filters what shows up as a suggested result in the geocoder dropdown suggestions, but it doesn't allow us to put a marker on all of the results at the same time. The only time we seem to have access to multiple results at the same time is in the geocoder.on('results', callback) method. But once the user pushes enter, it will execute the highlighted result suggestion in the geocoder, and drop the rest. How can we put markers on all of the results?

Comment: Right, put a listener on the `results` event, and put them all on the map then. What's the problem with that?

Comment: That works when the user types "cafe" but since there are several cafes that have the word "cafe" in their name, the first recommendation is going to be for some specific place. So when the user pushes enter, it's going to return the results for that specific place rather than keeping focus on the multiple general results. The issue is that there need to be keywords that trigger results with multiple locations, not just one.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I misunderstood the focus of the question, was distracted by the technicalities. You're trying to do a search for "all cafes in this area"? Don't use the geocoder, just use the `mapbox-streets` vector tiles and filter to cafes. It won't perfectly, and won't work at all at low zooms.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make this work but it's contrived. Let's take "cafe" as an example category search. Steve Bennett's suggestion to use mapbox-streets (in the comments of his answer) seems to be the way to go, but I'm documenting my answer here as an alternative in case it's useful to anyone else.

Step 1: Add an empty array of search hits for the search term that I want to support (in this case, "cafe" searches). I also need the longitude and latitude.

```
this.state = {
  cafes: [],
  lng: -74,
  lat: 40.8
}
```

Step 2: Add a localGeocoder function, and return a result for your search term, so that it comes up in the suggestions and the user can hit "enter" on it in the geocoder input field. Set the location of that point as the current center of the map, so that it doesn't move when you choose the "cafe" result.

```
const geocoder = new Geocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
  marker: false,
  localGeocoder: this.localGeocodingFunc
})

// ...

  localGeocodingFunc(query) {
    if (query !== 'cafe') {
      return [];
    }
    const cafe_result = {
      type: 'General cafe search',
      properties: {
        title: 'generic cafe',
        description: "Generic cafe search trigger"
      },
      context: [],
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
        type: 'Point'
      },
      place_name: 'cafe',
      text: 'cafe',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      place_type: ['cafe']
    }
    return [cafe_result];
  }
```

Step 3: Every time the user moves the map, update the geocoder's level of zoom to match that of the map so that you don't change your zoom level on selecting the "cafe" result. I also found it useful to set a bounding box so that the only cafe results in the current viewport show up.

```
map.on('move', () => {
  geocoder.setZoom(map.getZoom());
  geocoder.setBbox(this.viewportToBbox(map));
});

//...

  viewportToBbox(_map) {
    // Return the current viewport in a bbox array format.
    let {_sw, _ne} = _map.getBounds();
    return [_sw.lng, _sw.lat, _ne.lng, _ne.lat];
  }
```

Step 4: Listen for the "cafe" result, and if it shows up, then return the cafes listed in this.state.cafes. I use the jquery command here to remove any markers currently on the map which prevents markers piling up if you do this category search multiple times.

```
geocoder.on('result', (e) => {
  console.log('onResult e value:', e);
  $( ".marker" ).remove();
  if (e.result.text === 'cafe') {
    if (this.state.cafes.length > 0) {
      // Process these cafes however you want to put a marker on each one
    }
  }
}
```

So that's almost certainly not as elegant as Steve Bennett's suggestion of using mapbox-streets, but I haven't dug in to that yet and this at least works.